# Infinite scroll with jScrollPane

Tags: scroll, jscrollpane, infinite, jquery-jscrollpane

I'd like to implement a Facebook like control for auto loading of a paged content into a DIV with custom styled scrollbars. For custom scrollbars I use jScrollPane plugin, but can't figure out how to listen to an event when this scrollbar reaches its bottom to append additional html to this DIV. Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen for the `jsp-scroll-y` event and check the passed `isAtBottom` flag in your event handler. Details and demo [here](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/events.html).